# Display Text field data using multiple frames

Tags: java, frames

I am a noob to java and I have hit a snag building my gui...What I need to do is run my shipmentApp program which displays my EnterShipInfo frame that has several text fields to enter data and an enter button that when clicked passes the entered data to my ShipmentFrame. Initially when the frame pops up there should be three labels that just say "label" in them and a display button, then when you click the display button it the data from the text fields pops up in the three labels along with some other words to make a phrase.

//     ShipmentFrame code begins here

```
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private Label headerLbl = null;
        private Button displayButton = null;
        private Button Exit = null;
        private Label shipLbl = null;
        private Label empLbl = null;
        private Label dateTimeLbl = null;
        private Shipment s;
        private Shipment sf;



        public ShipmentFrame(Shipment ship){
            super();
            this.s = ship;
            initialize();
            s = ship;



        }


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            shipLbl.setText("Shipment number " + s.getShipmentNum() + 
                    " was received from "  + s.getSupplierName());
            empLbl.setText("By employee number " + s.getEmployeeNum());
            dateTimeLbl.setText("On " + s.getRevDate() + " at " +      s.getRevTime());

        }
```

// this is my code from EnterShipInfo

```
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private Label headerLbl = null;
        private Button displayButton = null;
        private Button Exit = null;
        private Label dateLbl = null;
        private Label timeLbl = null;
        private Label suplLbl = null;
        private Shipment s;
        private Label shipNumLbl = null;
        private Label empNumLbl = null;
        private TextField empNumTF = null;
        private TextField shipNumTF = null;
        private TextField dateTF = null;
        private TextField timeTF = null;
        private TextField supplTF = null;

        Shipment ship = new Shipment (" ", " ", " ", " ", " "); 

        //  @jve:decl-index=0:
        public EnterShipInfo(){
            super();

    //      this.s = ship;
            initialize();
        }
```

// This is the part that was wrong

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String employeeNum = empNumTF.getText();
            String shipmentNum = shipNumTF.getText();
            String revDate = dateTF.getText();
            String revTime = timeTF.getText();
            String supplierName = supplTF.getText();
            ShipmentFrame sf = new ShipmentFrame(null);


        }
```

//Below is what I was looking for...maybe someone knows more efficient way to accomplish this though

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ship.setEmployeeNum(empNumTF.getText());

    ship.setShipmentNum( shipNumTF.getText());
    ship.setRevDate( dateTF.getText());
    ship.setRevTime(timeTF.getText());
    ship.setSupplierName( supplTF.getText());
    ShipmentFrame sf = new ShipmentFrame(ship);


}
```

Comment: Is there a specific question you have or a specific problem you are facing here?

Comment: As a matter of fact there is a specific problem, it works up until the point of clicking the display button on the second frame (shipmentFrame)...when I click the display button I of course get errors, so my thought is I have made one of two possible mistakes, either I have not passed the info from the text fields to the objects or I have failed to call them upon clicking of the display button

Comment: copy and paste the errors into another code block in your question so we can see what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

So here's the general process for displaying a Component in a JFrame:

1 - Set up your JFrame (Layouts, borders, etc):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame Title");
JPanel contentPane = ((JPanel) frame.getContentPane());

contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1)); //use whatever kind of layout you need
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10)); //use whatever kind of border you need
```

2 - Initialize your Component(s) (in this case, two JTextFields and a JButton):

```
JTextField empNumTF = new JTextField("Initial text in field");
JTextField shipNumTF = new JTextField("Initial text in field");
JButton displayButton = new JButton("Display");
```

3 - Add your component(s) to the JFrame's contentPane:

```
contentPane.add(empNumTF);
contentPane.add(shipNumTF);
contentPane.add(displayButton);
```

4 - Pack and make visible:

```
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Then your JFrame should be displayed with those Components.

---

**ADDED**

Now, if we want to manipulate what the user enters into those text fields, we need to add an action listener for the button. To do this:

1 - Make one of your classes an *action listener* (you can use the same class that the JButton is created in if you want) by stating that it `implements ActionListener`:

```
public class EnterShipInfo implements ActionListener{
```

2 - Add an action-listening object to the button like so:

```
displayButton.addActionListener(this);
//using "this" means that the object this JButton was created in is the action listener.
```

3 - Add an `actionPerformed()` method to your ActionListener (as it seems you have already done correctly):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    //insert code to execute whenever your button is clicked.
}
```

---

So now, specifically to you, inside your `actionPerformed()` method, you probably want to handle it something like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Display")){ //"Display" is the text on the JButton
        String employeeNum = empNumTF.getText();
        String shipmentNum = shipNumTF.getText();
        String revDate = dateTF.getText();           //These text fields
        String revTime = timeTF.getText();           //not coded in
        String supplierName = supplTF.getText();     //my example
        ShipmentFrame sf = new ShipmentFrame(new Shipment(shipmentNum, supplierName, revDate, revTime, employeeNum)); //I'm just guessing at the order these come in
        sf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Some key documentation you may want to take a look at:

- [javax.swing.JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)
- [javax.swing.JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)
- [javax.swing.JTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)
- [javax.swing.JButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html)
- [javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/border/EmptyBorder.html)
- [java.awt.GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html)

Comment: Okay I may be missing your point, but I am pretty sure that I have done everything you mention in your answer...my problem is taking the information that is input into the text fields and passing them to be displayed into my other frame.

Comment: @philjd11 Okay, your question was kind of vague, so I just covered the basics, but I have now edited my answer so that it will hopefully cover what you are asking.